# deleting list of groups in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

In my query

```
SELECT  
    [Dt],
    [ItemRelation],
    [DocumentNum],
    [DocumentDate],
    [CalendarYear]
FROM
    [Action].[dbo].[testtable]
```

These columns are grouping:

```
  [ItemRelation]
  [DocumentNum]
  [CalendarYear]
```

Any groups I must delete.

So here data for query

```
DECLARE @LIST_ABOVE TABLE (ItemRelation NVARCHAR(10),
                           DocumentNum NVARCHAR(10),
                           CalendarYear INT)

INSERT INTO @LIST_ABOVE (ItemRelation, DocumentNum, CalendarYear)
VALUES
    (11511,5,2017),
    (11628,2,2017),
    (11661,163,2017),
    (11692,82,2017),
    (11709,143,2017),
    (13189,33,2017),
    (13284,2,2017),
    (158009,12,2017),
    (158121,63,2017),
    (11514,60,2017),
    (11628,3,2017),
    (11671,13,2017),
    (11706,8,2017),
    (11741,163,2017),
    (13191,7,2017),
    (13284,3,2017),
    (158010,12,2017),
    (158122,41,2017),
    (11592,33,2017),
    (11628,140,2017),
    (11683,70,2017),
    (11706,50,2017),
    (13163,70,2017),
    (13191,33,2017),
    (13322,4,2017),
    (158010,89,2017),
    (158122,62,2017),
    (11594,9,2017),
    (11633,75,2017),
    (11683,140,2017),
    (11706,51,2017),
    (13163,75,2017),
    (13250,83,2017),
    (13322,36,2017),
    (158010,95,2017),
    (158122,63,2017),
    (11623,71,2017),
    (11634,154,2017),
    (11683,154,2017),
    (11706,58,2017),
    (13163,131,2017),
    (13269,50,2017),
    (157186,57,2017),
    (158121,41,2017),
    (11626,29,2017),
    (11661,143,2017),
    (11683,163,2017),
    (11709,81,2017),
    (13189,13,2017),
    (13269,66,2017),
    (157192,56,2017),
    (158121,62,2017)
```

When I run this script

```
DELETE T FROM [Action].[dbo].testtable T
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM @LIST_ABOVE 
              WHERE T.[ItemRelation] = [ItemRelation] 
                AND T.[DocumentNum] = [DocumentNum] 
                AND T.[CalendarYear] = [CalendarYear]);
```

from table, the rows with indicated above groups weren't deleted.
every group has 40 rows.

so 40*52=2080 rows must be deleted.

How to delete rows with this groups?

I just don't want do it manually. But I can not delete them.

Comment: I am not sure what's your question. Could you give more detail?

Comment: Are you sure you have matches in your testTable? If the datatypes were different MS SQL server would do the casting but there is a possibility that would cause a problem depending on your real datatypes. Your code works fine for me, here is the link to a demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d04e2a981204fa2eb3ce2fc6dfc66f27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, you've declared ItemRelation and DocumentNum as NVARCHAR(10) but inserted them as integers. In itself that's not an issue but if the data types in testtable are numeric, then a datatype mismatch could explain it.

```
DELETE T 
FROM [Action].[dbo].testtable AS T
INNER JOIN @LIST_ABOVE AS LA
ON LA.ItemRelation = T.ItemRelation
AND LA.DocumentNum = T.DocumentNum
AND LA.CalendarYear = T.CalendarYear
```

If that doesn't work, then I'd suggest trying to delete the first item in @LIST_ABOVE

```
DELETE FROM [Action].[dbo].testtable AS T
WHERE T.ItemRelation = 11511
AND T.DocumentNum = 5
AND T.CalendarYear = 2017
```

In the end you need to determine why no deletes occur. Data type mismatches seem most likely, data just not being there in [Action].[dbo].testtable is another possibility.

Comment: The biggest thank you. The problem by mismatch data type.